# Consequences of adding a user to a project but not to an organisation

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to understand the complete purpose of organisations in ADO. What I have understood is that an organisation groups projects, defines resources, extensions, billing, etc. that is related to the organization.

I am struggling with the user part of an organization. I can add users to an org giving them an access level. But I can also add users directly to a project without adding them to an organization at all.

What is then the consequence of this? Is then access level by default stakeholder for those users?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can add people to projects instead of to your organization. Users
>   are automatically assigned Basic features if your organization has
>   seats available, or Stakeholder features if not.

For this please refer to the **Note** of this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-users-table-view?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

When you add members to projects and you don't have billing set up, Basic access is automatically assigned, until you run out of seats available. When you add members to projects and you do have billing set up, Basic access is assigned only if your default access level is set to Basic. Otherwise, project members are assigned Stakeholder permissions.

You can refer to [Add members to projects or teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-team-members?view=azure-devops) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you add an user to a project that user will be added to the organisation as well. At least when the said user first logs in. The user will get the access level you define as default.